# using expr and tt in the same macro_rules

Tags: rust

Consider this macro

```
macro_rules! cmd_format {
    ($value: expr) => {
        $value
    };
    ($value: tt) => {
        stringify!($value)
    };
}
```

the compiler complains about `cmd_format!(*)`.

```
|     cmd_format!(*);
|                  ^ expected expression
```

Why `*` is not being matched as a token tree?

Comment: Because `*` is the start of a possible dereference expression. Once matched, it cannot stop or backtrack resulting in an error.

Comment: Try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d4206c0ada6aedaa0029a46de2b7279)